# Data grid view in win form does not re size with its content

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to re size the data grid view in windows form. There are two data grid view on my form and both are fed from the database. Is there any was I can resize the data grid view on the left so that it grows with the content length and width  and the data grid view shrinks with the content.

Given below is my code

```
private void show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(productGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
        //IEnumerable<Supplier> supplierQuery = from supplier in newNorthWindContext.Suppliers
        //                                      where supplier.SupplierID == rowIndex
        //                                      select new {} supplier;
        IEnumerable<Supplier> supplierQuery = newNorthWindContext.Suppliers.Where(supliers => supliers.SupplierID == rowIndex);

        supplierDataGridView.DataSource = ((ObjectQuery)supplierQuery).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["SupplierID"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["ContactTitle"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["Address"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["City"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["Region"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["PostalCode"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["ContactTitle"].Visible = false;
        supplierDataGridView.Columns["Address"].Visible = false;

        //supplierDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
        supplierDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode =
   DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

    }
    private void categoryDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Category category = (Category)this.categoryDropDown.SelectedItem;

        try
        {
            productGridView.DataSource = category.Products;
            productGridView.Columns["SupplierID"].Visible = false;
            productGridView.Columns["CategoryID"].Visible = false;
            productGridView.Columns["Category"].Visible = false;
            productGridView.Columns["Order_Details"].Visible = false;
            productGridView.Columns["Supplier"].Visible = false;
            productGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
            productGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
            productGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }



    private void ProductDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        newNorthWindContext = new NorthwindEntities();
        productGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode =
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        IEnumerable<Category> categoryQuery = from category in newNorthWindContext.Categories.Include("Products")
                                              orderby category.CategoryName
                                              select category;


        try
        {

            this.categoryDropDown.DataSource = ((ObjectQuery)categoryQuery).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
            this.categoryDropDown.DisplayMember = "categoryName";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want ot accomplish, The DataGridView is a control which size and position are defined at design-time. If you want your grid occupy all your form surface set the property Dock=Fill

Comment: @Steve. I dont want to fill the form with one data grid view. I want that data grid to grow or shrink with its content. The idea might not be a suitable one for win form coz I was thinking from a web form perspective. Please let me know I have explained it well.

Answer (score 2):

This solves the issue.

```
supplierDataGridView.Width = supplierDataGridView.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)+4;
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of show_Click you should have something like

```
supplierDataGridView.Width = supplierDataGridView.Columns.Sum(x => x.Width) + supplierDataGridView.RowHeadersWidth + 2;

supplierDataGridView.Height = supplierDataGridView.GetRowDisplayRectangle(supplierDataGridView.NewRowIndex, true).Bottom + supplierDataGridView.GetRowDisplayRectangle(supplierDataGridView.NewRowIndex, false).Height;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for looking.what is x in your code? is it a column in the grid box.

Comment: add **using System.Linq;** if you are using .NET 3.5 or above, if not let me know

Comment: the expression with x is lambda, therefore x is a grid column

Comment: I am using Linq to entity. Here is the error I have got Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\sabuj.saha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PracticeWindowsFormLinq\PracticeWindowsFormLinq\ProductDetail.cs 76 46 PracticeWindowsFormLinq

Comment: ok, I didn't compile the code, you're right. try ...Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().Sum(x =>...

Comment: That did not solve my problem completely. However I have decided to move towards WPF, therefore is not going mess winForm any more. Thanks for trying. I have learn some new stuff here.